# Trigger.io sencha doesn't load on iOS

Tags: trigger.io

I am stuck on a blank white screen while loading Trigger.io iOS with Sencha 2.

It works fine on Android, but on iOS, it just shows a blank white screen.

Here's the debug output:

```
[INFO] 943E7E1BD31/Library/Application%20Support/Forge/assets-AA20D894-4614-43FB-BE67-D78F05175E9B/src/index.html
[DEBUG] Returning to javascript: {
[DEBUG]     event = \"internal.connectionStateChange\";
[DEBUG]     params =     {
[DEBUG]         connected = 1;
[DEBUG]         wifi = 1;
[DEBUG]     };
[DEBUG] }
[DEBUG] Native call: {
[DEBUG]     callid = \"C812FD5E-EFAE-4BCD-A3EE-CFB2574F70EA\";
[DEBUG]     method = \"internal.hideLaunchImage\";
[DEBUG]     params =     {
[DEBUG]     };
[DEBUG] }
[DEBUG] Returning to 
[DEBUG] script: {
[DEBUG]     callid = \"C812FD5E-EFAE-4BCD-A3EE-CFB2574F70EA\";
[DEBUG]     content = \"<null>\";
[DEBUG]     status = success;
[DEBUG] }
```

After hiding launch image, it's calling `content = \"<null>\";` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out Sencha 2 has a bug, it was throwing an error like this:

```
Error: [ERROR][Ext.viewport.Ios#undefined] Timeout waiting for window.innerHeight to change
```

I did some research, and it seems to be a bug relating to Safari vs. UI Web View.

To solve this problem, add this under `Ext.application({`

```
viewport: { autoMaximize: false },
```

Cheers